# Caught exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'complete' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I keep getting the error in the title upon user creation in my node/ express/ mongo setup.

Here is the code that throws:

```
app.post("/api/user", function(req, res) {

        if (req.session.user)
        {
            res.send(409, "You are connected, you can't create an account");
            return false;
        }

        var email = req.param('email');
        var password = req.param('password');
        if (!email || !password || email.length < 3 || password.length < 3 || !email.match(config.emailRegex))
        {
            res.send(400, "Please provide a correct email and a correct password");
            return false;
        }
        database.user.create(email, password, function (user, err) {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log("[error] user %s already exist", email);
                res.send(409, "This user already exist");
                return false;
            }
            console.log("[info ] Creating new user %s", email);
            req.session.user = user.emitted.complete[0];
            res.send("User created");
        });
    });
```

I think the problem is in the `req.session.user = user.emitted.complete[0];` but since I'm newish to this, I haven't had any luck with things tried.

Ideas?

Comment: Try some basic debugging like console.log(user) just above the req.session.user command. Probably there is no array called complete in the emmited key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add fail-safe code:

```
if(user && user.emitted && user.emitted.complete){
    req.session.user = user.emitted.complete[0];
}
```

Comment: This helped, thanks! I will also spend some time debugging user.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue in callback arguments.
The first argument of the callback is reserved for an error object

```
database.user.create(email, password, function (err, user) {
  //rest of your code will go here..!!!
})
```